# Dismissing Custom MKAnnotationView Callout

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am customizing the MKAnnotationView by using this

http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

This works for single annotation. However, I want to use this for the multiple annotations. But the problem is that I am not able to give it a behavior of the original SDK's Pop up. For instance,

1. If you touch outside the pop up fades out.
2. Click on one pop up the previous pop up goes. Or click on the same pop up the nothing happens to the popUp.

How can I fix this?

Comment: see part two of the same post - http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-2/ to get ideas about how to fix the second problem. the first one where the popup disappears on touching outside should already work from the first tutorial.

Comment: thts works in the blog code because they have only one custom pop up and they can manage to prevent that particular pop up to be isolated from touches . I have already seen the code but that doen't really help to solve the problem with multiple custom annotations

Answer (score 1):

See [Customize the MKAnnotationView callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018841/customize-the-mkannotationview-callout/8019308#8019308) and the usage section of https://github.com/j4n0/callout Adding another custom annotation requires you to create a subclass of CalloutView.