# mapKit use map overlay as button

Tags: ios, button, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am trying to create a simple app where the user is able to search for a location. At certain locations I would like to use map overlays to function as buttons. Is this even possible to do? I am very new to xcode and have been unable to find any documentation on this. My MKmapview and UISearchBar are functioning properly but I have no idea where to start to integrate a button at a specified location. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: consider a UI where the map has annotations and when you tap an annotation, the callout that pops up has a button in it.... might look less cluttered...

Comment: Ah excellent suggestion thank you I did not think of that. Will I be able to customize a button as an image in the callout? The idea was for it to be a logo of the business at that location.

Comment: you can specify your own view, so yes

Comment: Personally, I create a custom annotation, and I can custom its view (adding a button or whatever). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17772487/1271826.