# Custom Callout Dialogue for map annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I don't know much about the MK_MapView, but I inherited a project that needs to have a custom dialogue popup when the user taps an annotation on the map.

Currently the dialogue is a custom MKAnnotation that uses the title, subtitle and detail disclosure.  I need a dialogue that essentially looks exactly the same but with one additional line added to it under the subtitle.

I have yet to find a good guide or steps to crate a custom callout dialogue.

I found this [Custom MKAnnotation callout bubble with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772108/custom-mkannotation-callout-bubble-with-button) but when i do the steps provided in the didSelet method, i get a display of both the custom popup and the original, displayed on top of each other.

How can i get what i need?

Thanks

Comment: lol, seriously?  Your half excuse of an answer didn't explain anything.  Grow up.  And check your anger issues at the door.

Answer (score 1):

Where you create your MKAnnotationView in (If you don´t have implement this methods, is part of MKMapViewDelegate) copy like that, near that (- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view):

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
 static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"reuseIdentifier";
 MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;



 return annotationView;
 }
```

Comment: The original callout is not displayed