# How to change MapKit callout background color?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

If I try to customize both annotation view and callout view in some map view I cannot find a way to change all callout view background (may be it's not a callout view itself but I need to customize all required map view UI). Just changing a background color of a view used for `detailCalloutAccessoryView` property (that has `UIView?` type) that's the most common suggestion I find over the Web I get  [the following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GO2t.png). But I don't need white edges around the mentioned view, I need to set the same black color to all the callout  view. How can I make it to change the color actually.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize MKAnnotation Callout View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793315/customize-mkannotation-callout-view)

Comment: Theoretically it duplicates but the problem is all the mentioned suggestions do not work actually. Also a can note that the all the question related suggestion match the most common one to change the background color but it doesn't work actually.

Answer (score 1):

You may add a subview to it with your preferred color see here custom calloutView see my example here [customPinAnnotationButton](https://github.com/ShKhan9/customPinAnnotationButton)

Comment: Does it customize some callout view? I cannot find it in the repo. It looks to customize only annotation views.

Comment: click the annotation and the customm callout will show

Comment: create the layout programmatically and use it