# Annotations under callout gets triggered when touching callout on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I'm having trouble with these annotations...

First when opening the app on iOS 6 devices the pins would show on top of the callout, which could be fixed with:

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
  [super didMoveToSuperview];
  [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
```

from: [Custom Annotation View do not work on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605249/custom-annotation-view-do-not-work-on-ios6)

Now when I tap the callout, the pins underneath gets triggered closing the current callout and opens the new one.

I've have tried overriding:

```
touchesBegan:, touchesMoved: and touchesEnded
```

and not calling super within them, to prevent the call propagate to layers behind it - without any luck...

Any ideas anyone? It works fine on iOS 5...

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your delegates before adding annotations - if you haven't