# Custom CallOut not displayed correctly in ios6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, mkmapview

As i want to implement the custom call out in the mkmapview i am using these classes  CalloutMapAnnotationView.h and CalloutMapAnnotationView.m

I have extracted these classes from the following links

https://github.com/asalom/Custom-Map-Annotation-Callouts/blob/master/Classes/CalloutMapAnnotationView.h

https://github.com/asalom/Custom-Map-Annotation-Callouts/blob/master/Classes/CalloutMapAnnotationView.m

These work fine in ios5 but in ios6 when i am clicking on the call out the map view is moving and call out is not showing correctly as shown in the below figures while i was zooming also its not coming correctly i have tried several ways to get rid out of this problem by checking the version of os and tried to change the some of the methods in the classes but of not use.

After implementing these in ios5 map view coming like this 
[image]

In Ios6 This one not coming properly as like in ios5. for example 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too have faced the same problem in `iOS 6` using these classes. These changes worked for me:

1) Change in this method:

This method you will implement in your map view class

```
(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView*)view
```

as following order of lines

```
self.selectedAnnotationView = view;

[self.mapView addAnnotation:self.calloutAnnotation];
```

2) In CalloutMapAnnotationView.m file

```
- (void)adjustMapRegionIfNeeded in this method first 5 lines like bellow

    CGFloat xPixelShift = 0;

   if ([self relativeParentXPosition] < 38) {

        xPixelShift = 38 - [self relativeParentXPosition];

   } else if ([self relativeParentXPosition] > self.frame.size.width - 38) {

  xPixelShift = (self.frame.size.width - 38) - [self relativeParentXPosition];

   }
```

3) In same class CalloutMapAnnotationView.m -   `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` in this method after`CGFloat parentX = [self relativeParentXPosition];`

line and above `rect = self.bounds;` this line
add following lines

```
    if ([self relativeParentXPosition] < 38) {

       parentX = 38;

   } else if ([self relativeParentXPosition] > self.mapView.frame.size.width - 38) {

       parentX = [self relativeParentXPosition]-25;

   }
```

4) In same class CalloutMapAnnotationView.m.

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
        [super didMoveToSuperview];
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
```

You can use directly the above classes and use them they work fine in both iOS 5 & iOS 6.
You should make necessary changes according to your requirements.

Comment: It solved the problem but now if I move map to most left or most right and tap on the pin then it looks like [**this**](http://postimg.org/image/a3u3k2eo5/). Please check the image I've uploaded. Let me know if you solved this too.

Answer (score -2):

just u can add nsstring title and nstring subtitle like that and 
_name is what title u want .

```
- (NSString *)title {
    return _name;
}
- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", _coordinate.latitude, _coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Comment: this is not what is being asked at all