# How to show custom callout with two button in mkmapview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, callout

I want to show a custom callout with two button , and I also want action on both buttons ,

[image]

I try that but not do this type of callout on map, this isn't really exactly what I wanted. As I am making an iPhone application, Since I am new to MKMapview its getting difficult for me to do the same. How to show custom callout with two button?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018841/

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Left and right calloutaccessoryview Look at [**HERE**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207)

```
//ANNOTATION VIEW SETTING DELEGATE
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
     MKPinAnnotationView *myPin  =   [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"reuseString"];
    myPin.draggable             =   NO;
    myPin.canShowCallout        =   YES;
    myPin.pinColor              =   MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    UIButton *rightButton   =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rightButton.frame       =   CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
    [rightButton setTitle:@"Info!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rightButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted   =   YES;
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rightAcccoryViewButtonCLicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //rightAcccoryViewButtonCLicked is a function

    myPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return myPin;

}
```

Similarly you can use the **leftCalloutAccessoryView** and add another button.

Comment: hello sir , i try this code , in this have default callout , but i want big callout  , in this callout have two button & one lable and i also want action on the both button , so please help me....

Comment: @user1687868 with above approach you can achieve what you want a lable and two buttons with actions, but if you still need a bigger callout view than the default one, than you have to subclass the map annotation class here is a tutorial with source code http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0Yp2vE8AxWkJ%3ablog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/&hl=en&strip=1