# Showing view after selecting map annotation

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am trying to create custom map annotations on a map view with data from an array and also showing a UIView when selecting each map annotation (similar to callout). However, the UIView sometimes doesnt show when the map annotation is being selected and the data shown on the view is from the last element of the array. Is there a problem with the view(infoView)? Btw, the view is created below the map view in a view controller.

Comment: Something similar to this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018841/customize-the-mkannotationview-callout

Comment: Please post the code (edit into your question) where you show the view and how it determines which annotation was selected.