# Customize image the MKPointAnnotation

Tags: ios, mkannotationview, ios7

I have for some time looking for some way to find a way that the result is like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f78oz.png]

-but I enters the method, I would like to know if I putting the code in the right place, to have if you could help me, thanks

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableIdentifier"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_right.png"]];

    annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    [annView addSubview:imageView];
    return annView;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018841/customize-the-mkannotationview-callout