# Button action in mkannotation view not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Hello i have stuck in one situation on map where i have managed to show custom annotation. When the annotation is tapped i have to show  a view with some information and one button. when user taps on the button then one alert should display.

code is as follows

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
       if (![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

          POCustomAnnotation *annotation = (POCustomAnnotation *)[view annotation];

          UIView *bgview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-30, -150,130, 150)];
          bgview.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
          UILabel *templbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 120)];

          templbl.text=annotation.displayText;
          templbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
          templbl.numberOfLines=10;

          [bgview addSubview:templbl];

          UIButton *tembtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];        
          [tembtn setTitle:@"More info" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [tembtn addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationBtnAction:)     
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];         
          tembtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];   
           tembtn.frame=CGRectMake(0, 121, 130, 30);       
          [bgview addSubview:tembtn];


          [view addSubview:bgview];
    } else {

          POMapAnnotationView *callout = (POMapAnnotationView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"POMapAnnotationView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
          view.canShowCallout = NO;
          CGRect calloutViewFrame = callout.frame;
          calloutViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(-calloutViewFrame.size.width / 2 + 15, - calloutViewFrame.size.height);
          callout.frame = calloutViewFrame;
          [callout setLabelText:[self distanceText]];
          [view addSubview:callout];
     }
 }
```

I am trying to handle this

```
 [tembtn addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationBtnAction:)     
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which is not getting called.
and my screen looks like this

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can add the button as subview to your bgview. Also add [view sizeToFit]; and the action which you want to perform on button click, you can write that code in didSelecetAnnotation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set frame for this button. which is not really seen in the code. Adjust frame as you want by x position and y position.

```
UIButton *tembtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// Frame required to render on position and size. Add below line 
[tembtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];

[tembtn setTitle:@"More info" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tembtn addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationBtnAction:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
tembtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[view addSubview:tembtn];
```

**Edit:**

Found the reason ***you can only tap on area, in which annotation is rendered.***

Here is simple demo for custom call out:

### [Custom Callout Demo](http://jmp.sh/cKcBvCs)

### [image]

Comment: i have edited my question but still didDeselectAnnotationView method called instead of button action

Comment: @ismail - A sample demo for you.