# Multiple Pin subtitle annotations in MapKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am parsing data from a csv file with coordinates and other information. I have the pins plotted and I would like to know how to add other pieces of data in the subtitle object of the pins. Here is my approach (the object I'm trying to add is "temperature"):

ViewController.h

```
    NSString * latitude = [infos objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString * longitude = [infos objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString * description =[infos objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString * address = [infos objectAtIndex:4];
    NSString * temperature = [infos objectAtIndex:5];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
    coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;
    Location *annotation = [[Location alloc] initWithName:description address:address temperature:temperature coordinate:coordinate] ;
    [mapview addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Location.h

```
@interface Location : NSObject  {
NSString *_name;
NSString *_address;
NSString *_temperature;
CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
}

@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *address;
@property (copy) NSString *temperature;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address temperature:     
  (NSString*)temperature coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
```

Location.m

```
@implementation Location
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize address = _address;
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize temperature = _temperature;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address temperature:(NSString*)temperature coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    _name = [name copy];
    _address = [address copy];
    _temperature = [temperature copy];
    _coordinate = coordinate;
}
return self;
}

- (NSString *)title {
if ([_name isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    return @"Unknown charge";
else
    return _name;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
return _address;
return _temperature;

}
```

As you can see I tried to add the "temperature" object in the "subtitle" method, unfortunately that didn't display in the annotation. Right now I am trying with the temperature object but I need to plot some more so I need a way to add as many objects as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `subtitle` method:

```
- (NSString *)subtitle {
return _address;
return _temperature;

}
```

nothing after the `return _address;` line will execute.

That's how a `return` statement works (execution returns immediately to the caller).

Don't confuse the arrangement of the code with how the variables mentioned are displayed in the user interface.

Additionally, the built-in callout in MapKit only supports one short line each for the `title` and `subtitle`.  Trying to display more than one line in each property will lead to disappointment.

So you could do:

```
- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return _address;
}
```

or:

```
- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return _temperature;
}
```

or:

```
- (NSString *)subtitle {
    //display "address, temperature"...
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", _address, _temperature];
}
```

If you must display a callout with a lot more detail than the default, you'll need to code a custom callout view which can get complex.  See [Custom MKAnnotation callout bubble with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772108/custom-mkannotation-callout-bubble-with-button) and [Show custom and default callout views on different pins with pin clustering on map view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636029/show-custom-and-default-callout-views-on-different-pins-with-pin-clustering-on-m) for a couple of examples to start with if interested.

---

By the way, unrelated but, the `Location` class should declare that it implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol.  This will help you and the compiler avoid or display appropriate warnings and self-documents the code as a side benefit:

```
    @interface Location : NSObject<MKAnnotation>  {
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) If its not much to ask, do you know how I could separate each object by moving it a line down instead of a coma or a space next to it and also, how to have fixed characters, for example, for temperature I don't receive the data with the "ºCº symbol in the end I would like to write it so it comes up in the annotation. Thanks once again.

Comment: You can't move it a line down because the default callout doesn't support a dynamic height.  Learning how to [format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) NSString's is [basic Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).  Example: `return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp is %@°C", _temperature];`