# Set Custom Callout as UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone

I Need to set Customise Annotation View Callout ,So Possible to Set UITableviewCell to Show for Each callout

Comment: To create custom call out, check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519517/button-action-in-mkannotation-view-not-working/27519673#27519673