# Making clickable area larger on MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkannotation

I'm making a custom MKAnnotation where I return a UIButton. My question is if there's any way to make the clickable area of that UIButton larger than the actual button? I've tried adding the button to a larger UIView with a tapGestureRecognizer, but it dosen't seem that the gestureRecognizer is ever called.
Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
To clarify: It is the annotation "pin" which is custom, not the "pop-up-view". I want the user to easily be able to hit the pin :-)

Comment: Follow this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519517/button-action-in-mkannotation-view-not-working/27519673#27519673. Make transparent view will handle tap for the button.

Comment: Looks promising - thanks @Kampai, I'll let you know how it works out